# double-click delete bug (?!) in chrome contenteditable

Tags: html, google-chrome, contenteditable

This is an html page that duplicates the error: `<span contenteditable style="border:1px solid black">content</span> something after`

I'm using chrome version `23.0.1271.97 m` on windows 7.

If you double-click the span in my example to highlight it, then type <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> to clear it, chrome copies the following text node ('something after') into the span.

My request: any ideas on what's happening, and any solution that doesn't involve installing event handlers.

Note: I didn't test this on my 1980s version of IE, but firefox 11.0 refuses to select-all in a contenteditable span from a double-click.
Note 2: single-click followed by <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd> doesn't manifest the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same bug still exists in Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m on Windows 7.

I found out that the bug only applies to elements with `display: inline` and changing it to `display: inline-block` is a usable workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been searching for a solution for hours! Great solution.